# Create FMX window with MessageBox style

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey, messagebox, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a question: how I can create FMX window to make it looks like ShowMessage window?

ShowMessage (contain **Move** and **Close** items):

[image]

FMX window:

```
BorderIcons := [TBorderIcon.biSystemMenu];
BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle.Single;
```

[image]

What I need: remove Icon and delete disabled menu items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, `ShowMessage()` displays a system dialog using the Win32 API [`MessageBoxIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645511.aspx) function.

To customize the default system menu of a standard FMX form, you have to drop down to the Win32 API layer and manipulate the system menu directly.  That means getting the `HWND` of the Form (you can use the [`FormToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function in the [`FMX.Platform.Win`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Platform.Win) unit) and then use the Win32 API [`GetMenu()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640.aspx) and [`DeleteMenu()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647629.aspx) functions.

To remove the Form's icon, use the Win32 API [`SendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) function to send the `HWND` a [`WM_SETICON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643.aspx) message with the `lParam` set to 0.  Or use `SetWindowLongPtr()` to enable the `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` window style.

Override the Form's virtual `CreateHandle()` method to perform these operations, eg:

```
interface

...

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  protected
    procedure CreateHandle; override;
  {$ENDIF}
    ...
  end;

implementation

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
uses
  Windows;
{$ENDIF}

...

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
procedure TForm1.CreateHandle;
var
  Wnd: HWND;     
  Menu: HMENU;
  ExStyle: LONG_PTR;
begin
  inherited;
  Wnd := FormToHWND(Self);

  Menu := GetMenu(Wnd);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, SC_TASKLIST, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, 7, MF_BYPOSITION);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, 5, MF_BYPOSITION);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  DeleteMenu(Menu, SC_RESTORE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

  SendMessage(Wnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0);
  SendMessage(Wnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);

  ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  SetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle or WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
  SetWindowPos(Wnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
end;
{$ENDIF}

...

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know that this is possible with WinApi functions. On the FMX form caption showed system menu too, this is not a custom Delphi menu. Question was about changing FMX window style with delphi level functions, not with low level WinApi functions. Do you think this is possible with API only? For example I can assign `BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle.Single;` - window will be without icon but with smaller close button, which is constanly red

Comment: An FMX Form wraps a standard Win32 `HWND`. The menu you are seeing is a standard Win32 system menu. The .`biSystemMenu` flag merely enables the `WS_SYSMENU` style on that `HWND`, the rest is handled by the OS itself. The `BorderStyle` simply sets enables/disables other window styles on the `HWND` as needed (`WS_POPUP`, `WS_BORDER`, `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`, etc). You must use the Win32 API directly to manipulate the contents of the system menu. What you are asking for cannot be done in FMX alone.

Comment: Thank you, you are completely right, on VCL we have bsDialog value and for this value Delphi makes all this work internally in `TCustomForm.WMNCCreate` using function `ModifySystemMenu` and with FMX we should to do this manually

Comment: Which event handler of the FMX form is correct place to use this code, OnPaint? In OnPaint now removing menu items works fine, but icon is not removed: `SendMessage(hWindow, WM_SETICON, 0, 0);` where `hWindow := FormToHWND(Self);`

Comment: You need to do this right after the Form creates its `HWND`.  Override the Form's virtual `CreateHandle()` method, call `inherited` first, then call `FormToHWND()` and operate on the `HWND` as needed.

Comment: Thanks, `SendMessage(hWindow, WM_SETICON, 0, 0);` is not working in `CreateHandle` too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139305/discussion-between-alex-egorov-and-remy-lebeau).